# How can i make a inline keyboardbutton with telebot for a chatterbot?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api, telebot

I am making a chatterbot and I wonder how can I put inlinekeyboardbutton, how can I make that?
I need a code of keyboardbutton that handles a big conversation, please and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
import telebot
from telebot.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton

TELEGRAM_TOKEN = '<TOKEN>'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(TELEGRAM_TOKEN)

def gen_markup():
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.row_width = 2
    markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton("Yes", callback_data="cb_yes"),
                            InlineKeyboardButton("No", callback_data="cb_no"))
    return markup

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_query(call):
    if call.data == "cb_yes":
        bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, "Answer is Yes")
    elif call.data == "cb_no":
        bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, "Answer is No")

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def message_handler(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Yes/no?", reply_markup=gen_markup())

bot.infinity_polling()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Also add some more information's to you solution. Code-only is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create buttons with the code below:

```py
from telebot import types

markup = InlinKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)  # row_width: number of buttons

some_item = types.InlineKeyboardButton("text of your button", 
                                       callback_data="main info")

markup.add(some_item)
```

Comment: Please use correct upper case letters.